# Replace "\" to a String

Tags: java, android

I have a URL string

```
http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2170585961\/ETimes_normal.png
```

I want replace `"\"` by `""` but I use:

```
String.replaceAll("\","");
```

And it display error. How do i must?

---

(Retreived from [this url](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@android&rpp=25&page=1) key profile_image_url)

Comment: In your string the aren't "\" the are some "/", I think that is the problem, but please could you edit your qeustion, and add the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead, it repleaces all occurrences!

```
str = str.replace("\\", "");
```

---

From your example:

```
String u = "http:\\/\\/a0.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/2170585961\\/ETimes_normal.png";
System.out.println(u.replace("\\",""));
```

Outputs:

```
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2170585961/ETimes_normal.png
```

---

*Note that [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method takes a regular expression and in this case you don't need it..*

Comment: I use replace and it also error because "\" is a special char.

Comment: @user1423447: you need to quote it (using another backslash `\\`), see my update..

Comment: you must use this code : String.replaceAll("/","");
you are wrong. In your url you haven't any "\".

Comment: @AliSh: He wanted to replace `"\"`.

Comment: @user1423447: the solution still works, updated with example.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
String.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

As the first argument is a regular expression, there should be two backslashes (`\` is a special character in regex). But it's also a string, so each backslash should be escaped. So there are four `\`s.

Comment: Good, but now it works but looks pretty ugly. :) (reverted -1) but please use `replace` method as you often don't need regular expressions...